# Pattern/function finding program in python

Tags: python

I am looking for a program in python that can find a pattern or a function for a list of numbers. For example, if the input was `2, 4, 6` the program would output something like `f = 2n`. But the program must be able to handle very, very complicated, and extremely long inputs. Does anyone know of any such program?

Comment: keep looking at the difference of every two numbers, and the difference of that. Then build your way back up the triangle

Comment: More info here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/integer-sequence-learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On stackoverflow you are not supposed to ask for exact code without trying code first. I'll give this function to experiment with:

```
def diff(listy):
    sed=[]
    loop=-1
    for elem in listy:
        loop=loop+1
        try:
            sed.append(listy[loop+1]-listy[loop])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    print(sed)
    return(sed)
```

Put different lists of numbers into it and see what it returns. It may help you.

Comment: @wackamadoodle3000  I do understand that I just needed something to work with so thank you. Also, there is now output when I run the code thus I have been in able to use it

Comment: did you call diff? you need to call the function with a list parameter

Comment: after the function use `diff([1,2,3,4,5])` or whatever list you want

Comment: Thank you my diff was messed up